# Substract 2 hstore, You might need to add explicit type casts

Tags: postgresql, post, postgresql-9.1, psql

Documentation for postgres has hstore - hstore which delete matching pairs from left operand. Installed postgres extensions.

When I try

```
select public.hstore('"x"=>"30", "y"=>"c"') - 
       public.hstore('"x"=>"30","y"=>"fred"')
```

is error-ing with following

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: public.hstore - public.hstore
LINE 3:  select public.hstore('"x"=>"30", "y"=>"c"') - public.hstore...
                                                     ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Comment: try this one `'x=>30, y=>"c"'::hstore - 'x=>30, y=>"fred"'::hstore`

Comment: if i do not prepend public it does not find the hstore, if I run select 'x=>30, y=>"c"'::public.hstore - 'x=>30, y=>"fred"'::public.hstore then complains about operator

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've installed the `hstore` extension into the `public` schema, which is not on your `search_path`. To find the *types* you're schema-qualifying them but you're not qualifying the `-` *operator* that works on those types.

This means that `hstore`'s operator definitions will not be found. You must:

- Schema-qualify the operator using `OPERATOR(public.-)`;
- Put `public` on the `search_path`; or
- Uninstall `hstore` and then install it into its own dedicated schema that *is* on the `search_path`.

An example of schema-qualified operator syntax is:

```
SELECT 1 OPERATOR(pg_catalog.-) 2;
```

Comment: that's why I've asked OP to try hstore without schema :) +1

Comment: (public.hstore(new.*) OPERATOR(pg_catal... <-- operator does not exist

Comment: select public.hstore('"x"=>"30", "y"=>"c"') OPERATOR(pg_catalog.-) public.hstore('"x"=>"30","y"=>"fred"') .... No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: @user2624443 You installed `hstore` to `public`, not `pg_catalog`. So you must use `public.-`. I gave an *example of the syntax* that uses the `-` for integers that is in `pg_catalog`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well, nothing worked for me from my code (worked via pgadmin - query).  Eventually after looking at the functions within public I found this which worked for me.

```
public.fetchval(hstore, key)
```