# Accessing fields of records in triggers by column name passed as trigger arg

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, hstore

I have a set of tables which make use of a discriminator column to make distinctions about entity type. Certain of those tables describe either relationships between defined groups of entities or contain more information for a particular type of entity. I want to have integrity checks on the data in the table. Originally these were written as checks but postgres does not handle table ordering in backups well so I thought to rewrite the checks as triggers so that I can turn off the triggers when restoring the database.

Since the actual column name of entity will change from table to table and I would like to do it in a DRY fashion, I tried to write a single trigger function that took the id of the entity as an argument and verified that it was of the correct type.

I am trying to call a function trigger that takes an argument

```
c.is_earth_based_measurement_tg(bigint).
```

The actual trigger is written as follows:

```
CREATE TRIGGER earth_based_measurement_locations_tg1
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON measurements.earth_based_measurement_locations
  FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE c.is_earth_based_measurement_tg(NEW.fk_measurement);
```

when I try to save the trigger, I get 'ERROR: syntax error at or near "."' referring to NEW.fk_measurement. What is the proper way to write this trigger?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to pass `NEW.anything` as an argument; it's automatically supplied to the trigger function as the variable `NEW`. So your trigger can just access `NEW.fk_measurement` from anywhere within it, so long as `tg_op` is `INSERT` or `UPDATE` (`NEW` is not set for `DELETE` or `TRUNCATE` triggers).

Triggers can take arguments, but they appear (as zero323 notes) in `TG_ARGV`. They don't need to be used for column values, and in fact cannot reference column values; their purpose is for things like parameterized triggers, triggers with optional functionality, etc.

On re-reading your question you do need a parameter for the column name of interest. Unfortunately it's very awkward to access columns by dynamic name in the `NEW` tuple.

You'd create the trigger as:

```
CREATE TRIGGER earth_based_measurement_locations_tg1
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON measurements.earth_based_measurement_locations
  FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE c.is_earth_based_measurement_tg('fk_measurement');
```

i.e. passing the colname as a string literal.

The trigger procedure would be defined as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_earth_based_measurement_tg() RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
  IF tg_op = 'INSERT' OR tg_op = 'UPDATE' THEN
    PERFORM my_func(hstore(NEW) -> TG_ARGV[0]);
  END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

... or whatever else you want to do with the value you extract from the column.

You *cannot* set the value of the column in `NEW` via a dynamic column name in current PostgreSQL versions (up to and including 9.4).

Note that we convert the `NEW` tuple into a hstore, then de-reference it by column name.

Comment: In my question, I noted that the column name will change from table to table. If I trigger arguments cannot reference column values, then it looks like I can't do what I want to and have to write a trigger function for each different column name that I have.

Comment: @rozkosz Gotcha. Updated.

Comment: works, thanks. Had to use your [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18637669/substract-2-hstore-you-might-need-to-add-explicit-type-casts) and make sure that the variable was cast to bigint.

Answer (score 1):

Trigger functions cannot be declared with arguments. `OLD`, `NEW` and several trigger related variables are passed be default using so called `TG_ARGV` and can be accessed inside trigger functions without additional steps. You check [official documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql-trigger.html) for details but generally it should look similar to this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_earth_based_measurement_tg()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $earth_based_measurement_locations_tg1$
    BEGIN
       IF (NEW.fk_measurement = 'foo') THEN
           -- Do something
       END IF;
    END;
$earth_based_measurement_locations_tg1$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: How exactly do you pass the default TG_ARGV? I don't see an example of that on the page referenced by your link.